# storing HTML in Django data models

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates

is there a type of field for django data models that's for html? I want to have youtube embed links, which is a bunch of html fo putting a youtube video on your site. Itlooks like this: "". I stored it in a charfield, but it gets shown on the website as text.
What should I do?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It should be on CharField, you just have to render it by HTML

example if you are using django template:

```
<html>
 <body>
  {{ saved_html |safe }}
 </body>
</html>
```